# Is there a difference between "Recommend" and "Find"?

Tags: discussion, scope

I just saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30873587/try-to-find-a-specific-javascript-library) get closed because

> Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

However, I feel that if the question hadn't explicitly said "Or anything similar" the OP was simply asking to determine what library a specific website was using for a specific purpose. Is this really considered off-topic, and why?

Comment: Your question title and question confusing.You want to know the deference or why the question was off-topic?

Comment: I was hoping to determine why "finding" a software library as opposed to "recommending" a software library is considered off-topic.

Comment: Q+A needs to be useful to more than one person, SO is not anybody's personal helpdesk.  Since there is no dedicated closure reason for helpdesk questions, there is no "not constructive" anymore, SO users just pick whatever is closest.

Comment: I can't see the question at my rep level but the URL does say "Try to **find** a specific JavaScript Library". _what library a specific website was using for a specific purpose_ - It's still a request to find something.

Answer (score 3):

Questions asking what software/library/tool a specific website(s) use are off-topic. If you want to know what thing a website uses to do something cool, then check the source code of that site or email that website's support. It is not an appropriate question for Stack Overflow.

> Is there a difference between recommend and find?

Kind of sometimes. A recommend question would be like "Should I use this library A or that library B, or is there a library C that I should use but I'm not aware of?"

A find question usually doesn't give any options from the questioner himself/herself. Just asks if anyone knows where to find a tool that can do a,b, and c or resource that has a,b, and c.

Many recommend questions that list different libraries they are thinking about using could also end up being closed as primarily opinion based as well.

In conclusion, they're pretty much similar and can overlap. But the main point is they're off topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @HansPassant 's explanation makes a lot of sense. Any chance you can include the "should be useful to more than one person" in there somewhere?