# Is it out-of-scope to ask about the up-to-datedness of a book on programming?

Tags: discussion, scope, asking-questions

There's this book on low-level optimization of C++ code, and I want to ask whether it's up-to-date (the answer is not entirely obvious).

Is that off-topic/out-of-scope for Stack Overflow, or is it a valid question?

Comment: 99% (or some other arbitrary high number) chance it would be off topic.

Comment: Well, are you going to ask about the book or about information in the book you have trouble with?  The latter is pretty likely to be on topic, as long as you don't use the "is it up to date" phrase.

Comment: @HansPassant: I've started skimming through it and I get the sense it might be outdated despite have recent revisions.

Comment: You'd have to ask about a specific part of the book, something you could reasonably quote in a question. You'd also need to have a specific use (set) so we could actually determine if what you're wondering about is actually outdated for what you need.

Comment: I think if you quote the parts that make you suspicious and ask whether the advice/information therein is still relevant/idiomatic/up-to-date (in a given usage/context) then it will be an on-topic question.

Comment: A book regarding platform-independent, low-level optimization of C++ will get outdated fairly quick. So your book is not necessarily correct (any longer). This means that what you shouldn't do, is to ask questions based on incorrect benchmarking, such as "Since x is always faster than y, is this the right way to implement x". Because that has a very high probability of being a bad question. It is then better to first establish "is x always faster than y?" as a separate question.

Comment: The answer might depend partially on the book. Some books have such a towering influence on a language that a question like this might be of sufficiently general interest that it is (or should be) on-topic. For example -- a canonical answer to the question "Is K&R still a good guide to C programming?" might be useful (although possibly too opinion-based)

Comment: looks like a match to close reason text: ""Questions asking us to **recommend... a book...** are off-topic for Stack Overflow...""

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a difference between "Recommend" and "Find"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297076/is-there-a-difference-between-recommend-and-find)

Comment: @gnat: How is this question a dupe of that question? I'm not looking for recommendations, but about a book at hand.

Comment: it totally is. To ask whether book is up-to-date is the same as to ask whether it is recommended. Answer in duplicate explains how this is covered by the standard close reason

Comment: @gnat: There's a huge difference in scope between asking about a book (quote the relevant passage), and asking about all programming books in the universe.  "Recommend me a book" is the latter case, and has nothing at all in common with what einpoklum envisions asking.

Comment: @BenVoigt you gotta tell this to folks answering such questions with stuff like, "no this book is out-of-date, I recommend <that book> instead" (and good luck if you try to flag it NAA)

Comment: @gnat: "*To ask whether book is up-to-date is the same as to ask whether it is recommended.*" Not if "up-to-date" is reasonably well-scoped by the question. With "recommended", you're not providing any even semi-objective criteria. "*you gotta tell this to folks answering such questions with stuff like, "no this book is out-of-date, I recommend <that book> instead" (and good luck if you try to flag it NAA)*" Adding additional information which was not asked for, which the user feels might be helpful in this circumstance, is always valid for answers.

Comment: @gnat I can say whether or not a book is up-to-date without saying whether or not I think that it's a good book (which is excessively opinionated) or whether I recommend another book instead (which is clearly off-topic). My concern is whether this question is too broad and/or opinion-based.

Comment: @EJoshuaS that sounds like a [yes/no answer question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773) or do I miss something?

Comment: @gnat I didn't say that it's a good question - I think that it would probably be too broad. I just don't think that it's off-topic.

Comment: Maybe ask on https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @rogerdpack: Are you just speculating or do you think it it's within scope there?

Comment: @rogerdpack this question would be a poor fit over there for the same reasons as at SO. Please abstain of recommending sites you're not familiar with. See **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: Hmm it's a book about programming so it doesn't seem like it would fit in cs. Perhaps "software recommendation" either...or maybe it would? Any other site it would fit better?  Somebody should make "programming recommendations" I guess LOL

Answer (score 67):

Asking whether a book *in its entirety* is "out of date" is very broad, as books tend to include lots of stuff. It also gives too much license for people to post a particularly bad excerpt or two and simply declare that, regardless of what else is in the book, the book should be avoided because of how badly it bungles those particular examples. Which, even when it's true (and I myself have said such things in comments on questions about book/tutorial materials), it is pretty opinion-based.

However, it's entirely reasonable to present an example from the book and ask if that particular example is "out of date," so long as there's a fairly concrete definition for that phrase.

Comment: In other words, you turn the question from a question about the book into a question about a concrete programming problem (which only incidentally comes from the book).

Comment: What if the book was about an old framework like Android version 1 for example? Should the user be doing the footwork to understand before hand that a large portion if not all of the APIs in the book are out dated?

Comment: @MaxYoung: That's a question about the Android 1 framework, not about the book. And even then, it's too big of a question, unless Google has specifically deprecated the entire thing.

Comment: Which leads to the next suggestion, that "out of date" means little by itself. If you're using Microsoft software written in 2001, which is not an unusual thing to be doing, then a book published in 2001 is probably relevant to your use of that software, even if it's not relevant to other software released later.

Comment: "ask if that particular example is "out of date"" - this always feels like a backwards way to ask a question to me. In the worst case you'd have an answer which says "no" and little else (because how do you prove something's *not* out of date?). A "yes" answer could either explain what's wrong with it or present a better alternative, but mixing the two will just lead to a Q&A that's not that useful, and the latter seems like the much more useful part. So to me the much better question would be to just ask how to achieve the thing the example sets out to do.

Comment: Ha, and even if the information is not out of date, the only proper answer to give on this site would be, "Not yet".

Comment: What if the book has 1000 examples, and I've read, say, the first 5 and have noticed they're all out of date? Can't I ask "is the rest outdated as well"?

Comment: @einpoklum: No. It's just too broad of a question.

Comment: Asking if something is out of date seems like a veiled way of asking if an approach is still the best way to do something.  When in reality, it either works or it doesn't work any more.

Comment: *"Do people still use spaces rather than tabs to indent? This Microsoft books suggests it as a modern style?"*

Answer (score 0):

Questions on StackOverflow are supposed to have a definitive answer, although there can be multiple different solutions to the same problem.

Judging whether something is "out-of-date" is completely subjective. It's also hard to quantify what portions of the book may be out of date.

Opinion questions are not allowed generally, for example I want to solve problem X, is it better to use Java or Python is not an allowed question because you are asking for an opinion rather than a solution.

Comment: Being "out of date" is not "completely subjective". A guide on 8086-assembly-based software optimization would be out of date.

Comment: So how do you judge objectively if the book is out of date then?

Comment: I'm not going to get into an epistemological argument here about how it wouldn't be an objective judgement since the criteria are subjective because I came up with them, or whatever. Sure, there are subjective gray areas, but not everything is in them.

Comment: @einpoklum Not if you're trying to write 8086 assembly code it's not.